# `apt-get install --fix-broken ubuntu-desktop` fails on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, package-management

How this started:

1. rebooted and realized gnome wasn't working
2. got a login terminal, tried to run `apt-get update` and realized network wasn't working either
3. fired up a live session and chrooted into my boot volume to see what was going on
4. did the usual (`update`, `upgrade`, `autoremove`, `autoclean`, `install --fix-broken`)
5. basically, apt seems confused about whether I am no ubuntu3.8 or ubuntu3.13, I have no idea what that means or how it happenend

```
root@ubuntu:/# apt-get update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local  Release [564 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local  Release [564 B]
Get:3 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1484 B]                                                                                                           
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                            
Hit:5 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                
Hit:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                             
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                              
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Fetched 1484 B in 1s (1073 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done

root@ubuntu:/# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

root@ubuntu:/# apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

root@ubuntu:/# apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

root@ubuntu:/# apt install --fix-broken ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gdm3 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-appindicator but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: nautilus but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: pulseaudio
                  Depends: ubuntu-desktop-minimal but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: update-manager but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-disk-utility but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-initial-setup but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gvfs-fuse but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: nautilus-share but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: plymouth-theme-spinner but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: pulseaudio-module-bluetooth but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: usb-creator-gtk but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

root@ubuntu:/# apt-get install gdm3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdm3 : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.24) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.19.92) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

root@ubuntu:/# apt-get install gnome-settings-daemon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-settings-daemon : Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>= 2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: pulseaudio
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

root@ubuntu:/# apt-get install libpulse-mainloop-glib0 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

##### Update 1

```
root@ubuntu:/# apt policy ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-desktop:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.450
  Version table:
     1.450 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

##### Update 2:

Following comments below, I added the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, which seems to have resolved the issue:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
```

Comment: Certainly one or more of those many ppas is causing this problem. The output of `apt policy ubuntu-desktop` might yield some information.

Comment: thanks @OrganicMarble, I've updated the post with that info, but I have no idea what it means

Comment: That command shows you where it's trying to get the package from.  And your output, while unfortunately not directly revealing of the issue, raises many questions. Why don't you have the focal-updates repository? A normal Ubuntu focal system would try to install version 1.450.2 Did apt ever work properly on this system? If so, what is the last change you made?

Comment: yes its been running fine for years!  Basically, last week I was copy-pasting stuff I didn't understand to update the local environment so I could debug some code I am benchmarking on our cluster, while said cluster was down for maintenance, basically trying to save myself 48hrs of productivity...

Comment: can you explain how to add the missing focal-updates repository via the terminal?